# How to write a subquery in a select statement in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the need to write a Hive query that has a subquery in the select statement. Im aware that Hive does not support this, therefore I'm looking out for my options.

```
select
    a,
    b,
    (select max(tbl.c) from sample_table_a tbl where tbl.d like 'X012%') as d,
    e,
    f
from sample_table_b
```

How can I implement the above query in hive without using a cross join because sample_table_a contains about 40000 tuples and so does the sample_table_b.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an option:
There is going to be a single row in table `t` so join should not be that much a problem

```
    select
        a,
        b,
        max_value,
        e,
        f
    from 
        sample_table_b 
 
    inner join

    (
     select 
       max(tbl.c) as max_value
     from 
       sample_table_a tbl 
     where 
       tbl.d like 'X012%'
    )
    t;
```